# Snowflake compute costs by QUERY TYPE

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I could find a valid list of query types that generate compute costs on Snowflake.
Would you happen to know accurately which ones do generate cost please ?

Here is a list that i was able to extract from our execution logs : (table QUERY_HISTORY)

- ALTER
- ALTER_ACCOUNT
- ALTER_NETWORK_POLICY
- ALTER_PIPE ALTER_SESSION
- ALTER_TABLE
- ALTER_TABLE_ADD_COLUMN
- ALTER_TABLE_DROP_COLUMN
- ALTER_TABLE_MODIFY_COLUMN
- ALTER_USER
- ALTER_USER_RESET_PASSWORD
- ALTER_VIEW_MODIFY_SECURITY
- ALTER_WAREHOUSE_RESUME
- ALTER_WAREHOUSE_SUSPEND
- BEGIN_TRANSACTION
- COMMIT
- COPY
- CREATE
- CREATE_CONSTRAINT
- CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE
- CREATE_NETWORK_POLICY
- CREATE_ROLE
- CREATE_SEQUENCE
- CREATE_STREAM
- CREATE_TABLE
- CREATE_TABLE_AS_SELECT
- CREATE_TASK
- CREATE_USER
- CREATE_VIEW
- DELETE
- DESCRIBE
- DESCRIBE_QUERY
- DROP
- DROP_CONSTRAINT
- DROP_NETWORK_POLICY
- DROP_ROLE
- DROP_STREAM
- DROP_TASK
- DROP_USER
- EXPLAIN
- EXTERNAL_TABLE_REFRESH
- GET_FILES
- GRANT
- INSERT
- LIST_FILES
- MERGE
- PUT_FILES
- REMOVE_FILES
- RENAME_COLUMN
- RENAME_SCHEMA
- RENAME_TABLE
- RENAME_VIEW
- RESTORE
- REVOKE
- ROLLBACK
- SELECT
- SET
- SHOW
- TRUNCATE_TABLE
- UNKNOWN
- UNLOAD
- UNSET
- UPDATE
- USE

thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Metadata operations such as ALTER TABLE do not consume "compute costs", but I do not have a full list. I think you can use the same approach to find the query types to consume WH credits by checking the warehouse size:

```
select distinct query_type from snowflake.account_usage.query_history
where WAREHOUSE_SIZE is not null;
```

Comment: Another sub-question : does EXPLAIN generate costs ? EXPLAIN is not a query_type i see in my list, but it is detecte as SELECT etc. by Snowflake. So i am a bit in doubt about those ones.

Comment: Explain is a metadata operation, so it does not consume WH credits. I assume you are aware of CS costs https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/credits.html#cloud-services-credit-usage

Answer (score 0):

All operations generate a cost in some way. Operations that do not use a warehouse are usually run under the cloud services layer

Snowflake give you free CSL cost up to 10% of your compute costs. Over that and they start charging you for it

Answer (score -1):

Here's a SF query that tells you compute costs for the top 15 query types over a date range.

```
select query_type
    , count(*) freq
    , sum(CREDITS_USED_CLOUD_SERVICES) as total_CS_CREDITS
from snowflake.account_usage.query_history
where 1=1
and start_time = :daterange
group by 1
order by 3 desc
fetch 15 rows;
```

Comment: Computing a "query cost" like this can be misleading, as it assumes that the queries were single-threading in the warehouse cluster. Snowflake charges for the warehouse "up-time", not for each individual query in a cluster.

Comment: Good point. It's Snowflake's view, maybe they can explain it.